# deploy .net 4.0 wpf application problem

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, deployment, c#-4.0

I been working on a application that I am planing on distributing. For some reason I am not able to install it on other computers. first let me show you my deployment settings maybe I am doing something wrong in there (I left all the defaults).

### Deployment settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

after doing that I get the following files:

[image]

So far everything looks great! Let me show you what happens when I try installing this app on several computers:

.

### Computer 1: (Running windows 7 with Service Pack 1)

application installs in a matter of seconds and it works fine. 
I am able to uninstall it as: 
[image]

THE APPLICATION WORKS GREAT!

.

### Computer 2: (Running windows vista with service pack)

IT DOES NOT INSTALL:

[image]

when I click on install I get the following error:

[image]

so as you can see I was not able to install it on that machine. I tried uninstalling it then installing it again and I get the same problem.

.

.

### computer 3: (running windows xp with service pack 2)

when I ran the setup.exe file it took a while to download and install whatever requirements it needed. It took 1 hour to install what I believe was the:

[image]

and when that part finished at the end I got an error saying: "you do not have enough disk space" and I have 50GB of free disk space on my c drive.

SO IT DID NOT WORK WITH THIS COMPUTER EATHER.

.

.

### Computer 4: (windows xp with service pack 2)

I get the following error:

[image]

.
.
.
.
.

.

### why is it so difficult to deploy an application. this application works great in all the computers that have visual studio installed. Should I try to downgrade to .Net 3.0 or maybe .Net 2.0?

---

### Edit

Could this be because I might not be able to publish applications? I got visual studio for free because my university gave it to me. I know there are student versions where you can try and also that they expire every six months. I been using visual studio ultimate edition for about 1 year know and every time I launch visual studio it does NOT say for evaluation purposes only like on my laptop. My splash screen actually comes out as:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selected in your prerequisites the "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile", but is that what your application is targeting?  Check your application properties -> Application tab.  Usually a WPF application will target the full .Net framework.

Comment: I have that because that was the default. should I add the prerequisite that you are mentioning?

Comment: Yes, you want to require the full .net framework installation; the client profile is a smaller subset of the .net framework and will be missing import DLL's that your application probably relies on.

Comment: I also had to install windows imaging component (WIC) on the xp machines.   http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=32